# How can I compare a returned code/key that refer to a description?

Tags: java, android, regex, compare

I am using Jsoup to retrieve values from a website. One of the values is a code/Key number (12 for example) but the code returned could be anything from 0 - 30 and this code refers to a description i.e;

```
1 = yellow,  
2 = blue,  
3 = red,  
4 = green,
```

I know what the 'key numbers' mean as they are included on a different part of the website and I could included them in my project. But what is the best way to go about this?
I can obtain the exact 'key number' using jsoup but how can I compare that in my code to find the right description?

Getting the code/Key:

```
String Type = doc2.select("Rep:eq(2)").first().attr("W");
```

So how would I compare the number returned to the 'key' list of numbers and get the corresponding description?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach, I think, would be to use either a static array or map. If the codes are always integers from 0-30, an array would be the easiest to access, although you would first have to convert the `String` value into an integer (using `Integer.valueOf(String)`). If you want to stick with `String`-valued codes, then I would suggest a map. You can initialize these data structures statically, either in-line (in the case of an array) or in a `static` block (for either data structure):

```
static final String[] arrayLookup;
static final Map<String, String> mapLookup;
static {
    arrayLookup = new String[] {"yellow", "blue", "red", "green"};
    hashLookup = new HashMap<>();
    hashLookup.put("1", "yellow");
    hashLookup.put("2", "blue");
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I'm very much a novice learner at programming. Could you please explain how I would then compare my retrieved int to the values stored in the array? thanks

Comment: @J4C3N-14 - With the array approach, you would simply use `String description = arrayLookup(Integer.valueOf(Type));`. For the map approach, it would be `String description = mapLookup.get(Type);`. You could then do what you want with the descritpion. In either case, you might have to qualify the lookup data structure with a class name if the code were being processed in a different class. (I hope it is obvious that you would pick one or the other of these approaches; you certainly don't need the same data stored twice.)

Comment: Thanks, yes I think as you suggested the static array would be the best approach, I was thinking that as I wrote to you but failed to mention it. Thanks you for your quick help! much appreciated.